# import uuid "github.com/satori/go.uuid" and get "undefined: uuid.String"

Tags: go

main.go

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    uuid "github.com/satori/go.uuid"
)

func main() {
    uUID := uuid.NewV4()
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", uUID)
    uuidString := uuid.String(uUID)
    fmt.Println(uuidString)
}
```

When I run `go run main.go`, I got this error.

```
$ go run main.go 
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:12:16: undefined: uuid.String
```

NewV4() is running correctly.

go.mod

```
module github.com/Asuha-a/test

go 1.15

require (
    github.com/niemeyer/pretty v0.0.0-20200227124842-a10e7caefd8e // indirect
    github.com/satori/go.uuid v1.2.0
    gopkg.in/check.v1 v1.0.0-20200902074654-038fdea0a05b // indirect
)
```

go.sum

```
github.com/kr/pty v1.1.1/go.mod h1:pFQYn66WHrOpPYNljwOMqo10TkYh1fy3cYio2l3bCsQ=
github.com/kr/text v0.1.0 h1:45sCR5RtlFHMR4UwH9sdQ5TC8v0qDQCHnXt+kaKSTVE=
github.com/kr/text v0.1.0/go.mod h1:4Jbv+DJW3UT/LiOwJeYQe1efqtUx/iVham/4vfdArNI=
github.com/niemeyer/pretty v0.0.0-20200227124842-a10e7caefd8e h1:fD57ERR4JtEqsWbfPhv4DMiApHyliiK5xCTNVSPiaAs=
github.com/niemeyer/pretty v0.0.0-20200227124842-a10e7caefd8e/go.mod h1:zD1mROLANZcx1PVRCS0qkT7pwLkGfwJo4zjcN/Tysno=
github.com/satori/go.uuid v1.2.0 h1:0uYX9dsZ2yD7q2RtLRtPSdGDWzjeM3TbMJP9utgA0ww=
github.com/satori/go.uuid v1.2.0/go.mod h1:dA0hQrYB0VpLJoorglMZABFdXlWrHn1NEOzdhQKdks0=
gopkg.in/check.v1 v1.0.0-20200902074654-038fdea0a05b h1:QRR6H1YWRnHb4Y/HeNFCTJLFVxaq6wH4YuVdsUOr75U=
gopkg.in/check.v1 v1.0.0-20200902074654-038fdea0a05b/go.mod h1:Co6ibVJAznAaIkqp8huTwlJQCZ016jof/cbN4VW5Yz0=
```

I found the String function in GOPATH/pkg dir.

/home/asuha/go/pkg/mod/github.com/satori/go.uuid@v1.2.0/uuid.go

```
func (u UUID) String() string {
    buf := make([]byte, 36)

    hex.Encode(buf[0:8], u[0:4])
    buf[8] = '-'
    hex.Encode(buf[9:13], u[4:6])
    buf[13] = '-'
    hex.Encode(buf[14:18], u[6:8])
    buf[18] = '-'
    hex.Encode(buf[19:23], u[8:10])
    buf[23] = '-'
    hex.Encode(buf[24:], u[10:])

    return string(buf)
}
```

You can see the String function in [pkg.go.dev](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/satori/go.uuid@v1.2.0#UUID.String) too.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the declaration, `String` is a method of `UUID`, it is not a function that gets a UUID argument. So:

```
    uuidString := uUID.String()
```

Comment: I misunderstood that `func (u UUID) String () string` as ` func String (u UUID) string`. Thank you.